# Calculating Cost Based On 15 Minute Increments In Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, ms-office, vba

This one's confusing, I have a user who has requested an excel sheet that allows them to enter a time in minutes into cell A1 that will calculate a value to charge another company in cell C1. However the charging criteria is as follows:
£355.68 for the first hour,
£88.92 for every 15 minutes after that

AND if during one of those 15 minute increments the time goes over 7 minutes, it gets rounded up to a full 15 minutes or down if it's under 7 minutes. I have literally no idea where to even begin on this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the value in `A1` is simply a number of minutes and the charge is £355.68 for any time between 1 and 60 minutes, I think the following should work:

`=355.68+IF(A1>60,88.92*(FLOOR((A1-60)/15,1)+IF(A1-60-15*FLOOR((A1-60)/15,1)>7,1,0)),0)`

**Explanation:**

We start with the base cost of £355.68. The use of `FLOOR((A1-60)/15,1)` gives us the number of completed 15 minute intervals we have after the first hour. We initially multiply this by £88.92, and then we check how many minutes are left over once we take into account the first hour and any completed 15 minute period - `A1-60-15*FLOOR((A1-60)/15,1)`. If this is greater than 7, we add an extra £88.92 for the "partial completion".

Answer (score 0):

To round to the "closest" 15 minute interval, where the "split" occurs at 7 minutes, and you are entering your time as "Excel Minutes"  (e.g. the difference between a starting and ending time in minutes, or entered as, for example `00:42`, just add a bit less than 30 seconds to the time (e.g. 29 seconds), and then round to the nearest 15 minutes.

e.g: (one of the below)

```
=MROUND(A1+TIME(0,0,29),TIME(0,15,0))
=MROUND(A1+29/86400,15/1440)
```

or, using ROUND

```
=ROUND((A1+TIME(0,0,29))/TIME(0,15,0),0)*TIME(0,15,0)
=ROUND((A1+29/86400)/15*1440,0)*15/1440
```

You should be able to work out the rest.  If you can't, post what you have tried and where you are running into problems.